# Use mgo aggregate iterator data in upsert without unmarshaling

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

First of all, I am very new to go :)

I am trying to do an aggregate + upsert in mongo using go and mgo driver.

My code looks something like this:

```
pipe := c.Pipe([]bson.M{{"$match": bson.M{"name":"John"}}})
iter := pipe.Iter()
resp := []bson.M{}

for iter.Next(&resp) {
     //
     // read "value.sha1" from each response
     // do a:
     // otherCollection.Upsert(bson.M{"value.sha1": mySha1}, resp)
     //
}
```

The response from the aggregate collection can have lot's of formats, so I can't define a struct for it.

I just need to get one of the fields from the response, which is a sha1, and update another collection with the response received, based on the sha1 condition.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: In this case `interface` is the way to go.

Comment: Could you give me some more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood you but you can simply access returned documents as a `map`. Something like this:

```
pipe := c.Pipe([]bson.M{})
iter := pipe.Iter()
resp := bson.M{} // not array as you are using iterator which returns single document

for iter.Next(&resp) {
    otherCollection.Upsert(bson.M{"value.sha1": result["value"].(bson.M)["sha1"]}, resp)
}
```

Comment: This might be it. I am still getting `invalid operation: result["value"]["sha1"] (type interface {} does not support indexing)`

Comment: @Petru can you post result of `fmt.Printf("%+v\n", resp)`? Looks like your `resp` is not `bson.M` and this is strange.

Comment: `map[extracted_files:<nil> file_info:map[file_size:235933 file_type_description:Win32...` my error is at compile time

Comment: I can print `result["value"]`. `result["value"]["sha1"]` throws invalid operation.

Comment: @Petru try `result["value"].(bson.M)["sha1"]`

Comment: Worked like a charm!